# Removing cloud from Landsat Collection 2 Level 2 data

Tags: r, matlab, arcgis, qgis

I am working on Landsat data for my study. But, in that there is lot of cloud cover. I want to remove those clouds from my raster file. I tried pixel editor method in ArcGIS Pro but results are not promising. Is there any other method to do this? A little help would be appreciated.

I tried pixel editor method in ArcGIS pro in which I replaced the cloud area with some pixel extracted from other raster file for same location. But when I saved a new raster file and columns and rows of new raster were different despite of keeping the same resolution (30*30). Additionally there were some noData values in that file.